# How are microwaves blocked?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, absorption, microwaves

When a phone is inside a microwave oven and if we call it over Wi-Fi, the phone doesn't receive the call, because Wi-Fi and the microwaves generated in the oven have the same frequency and there is a mesh-like thing that blocks the microwaves.

But, since the void space of my trousers fabric have an even smaller diameter than those mesh holes, how is it that we can receive Whatsapp calls when the phone is in our trousers?

Comment: Are your trousers made of metal?

Comment: i hav posted the correct answer

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't agree with your "correct answer". Microwaves pass through cloth with or without holes unless the cloth has metal in it.

Comment: Please use standard punctuation and capitalization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Metal blocks microwaves. Cloth does not because it is not metal.

The purpose of the holes in the microwave door screen is to allow visible light to pass through so the user can view the oven contents. Microwaves don’t pass through the holes in the metal  mesh screen of the door because the diameter of the holes is about a millimeter and is much less than the wavelength of the microwaves, which is about 120 mm. The wavelength of visible light, on the other hand, is much smaller than the holes in the screen which therefore allows light to pass through.

Hope this helps

Comment: but holes in cloth are even small

Comment: @Sandeep Reddy But in order to block microwaves an object must both be made of metal and have small hole. Cloth is not made of metal as I said in the first sentence of my answer

Comment: @SandeepReddy The holes in the mesh are so we can see inside. The holes don't block the microwaves.

Comment: @AaronStevens Not sure of your point here. Perhaps it's the term "block". But microwaves do not pass through the holes  because the diameter are much less less than the microwave wavelength, whereas visible light (for viewing) does because the hole diameter is much greater than the wavelength of visible light.

Comment: @BobD I agree with that and your answer. I was addressing the OP. They seem to think that the point of the holes is to block the microwaves. I suppose I could have worded my comment better. I meant to say the purpose of the holes are not to block the microwaves. The microwaves still don't pass through them, but that's not what they are there for.

Comment: @AaronStevens Ah, I see now. I probably should have pointed out the purpose of the holes in my answer. I think I will update it. Thanks.